# RFID card programming cryptographically secure

Tags: security, cryptography, nfc, smartcard, rfid

I am trying to develop a custom cryptographically secure protocol for authenticating through an RFID smart card, all I can find over the internet are generic info on how write static Tags into the card.
For my project I need for the reader to send a Challenge nonce to the card (fixed length random bytes), then the card should send back the challenge encrypted with the hard-coded key (for example with AES CBC) or an hash HMAC.

The problem is: how can I program the card to do such behavior? I can write the code to do so, but how to "flash" it to the card. Also the code for the reader is not a problem (I want to use an Arduino with a reader module).

And then has a passive chip enough power to do this kind of calculations or is better to use an active one, considering that the distance would be few centimeters, such as behind a door?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A passive tag can't do this. Those just hold serial numbers that they spit out back.

You need some smarter card. You have basically two choices:

**1) Choose a general-purpose card that fit your needs**

The authentication scheme you describe is very widely used, and implemented by virtually all general-purpose smart cards, whether with contact or contactless (RF) interfaces (or both). If you go this way, you don't need to program the card with your own code, you just need to get the specs and initialize the card with the key value you want by sending the appropriate commands. And actually, with these cards, there are often generic tools available to initialize them. Easy.

**Mifare** (by NXP), for example is very widely used, easily available, and cards are cheap (drawback: it is certainly not the most secure cards ever made). You could use Mifare Classic - with proprietary NXP security protocol - specs [here](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MF1S50YYX_V1.pdf) (be careful, the reader must be compatible) or Mifare UltraLight *C*, with open 3DES crypto - specs [here](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MF0ICU2_SDS.pdf). There are other variants, as well (e.g. Mifare Plus, which uses AES). Just don't go for the simple Mifare Ultralight, which doesn't provide authentication means. You'll see that for all these type of cards, there is a builtin authentication scheme that can functionally fulfill your needs (it is actually a mutual authentication, so it does more that what you require, but it's fine).

**FeliCa** (made by Sony), **ACOS3** (made by ACS - specs [here](https://www.acs.com.hk/download-manual/6054/FSP-ACOS3-G1-1.02.pdf)) are other possibilities, although I'm less familiar with it.

**2) Get programmable cards**

There are some, but it is not very easy to find for contactless and they are very expensive. You can lookup:

**BasicCard** (ZeitControl), which exist with dual interface. Those cards are programmable in Basic, and there are some kits available (but I'm not familiar with it either).

**JavaCard** (any manufacturer), which is a standard, but those are hard to find for small volumes. A few online shops seem to have some, though. These cards are programmable in Java (actually a subset of Java). There are tools available for the development phase (from Oracle, or even as Eclipse Plugins, for example). Then, for loading your custom applet in the smart card, you need to get familiar with **GlobalPlatform**, which is another (publicy available) standard, describing the way applications are managed in a smart card. This would be too broad to describe in detail here, though. You can find resources on the internet, but this road is definitely the most difficult.

Comment: Thank you, I will proceed with a programmable card, I'm reading the documentation for BasicCard (for the easy .NET library and for contactless support) and also for JavaCard which seems to be cheaper. I found a lot of blank smart cards for both on online shops and I would prefer this to Mifare-like approach because I am more free to design my protocol and extra implementations that I can add later.

Comment: @GrowingBrick If you have time to allow for this, that's a great opportunity to learn stuff. I never used BasicCard actually. But I have practiced JavaCard a lot, and it is rather nice. The most difficult part, if you are a programmer, will not be JavaCard itself, but understanding GlobalPlatform, managing to open a secure channel on the card (given that there are different kind of protocols), and loading the applet code (called CAP file). But if you are able to find shops selling complete JavaCard SDKs including cards and software, you can make this part a no brainer.

Comment: I am trying to reconcile my understanding of these things. The characteristic of either being active or passive has no bearing on what a tag can or cannot do.

Comment: @typelogic. In fact, you're right, depending on your definition of active/passive. I am now on the way of becoming an old fart, and back in my days, the active/passive difference meant "chip that can do crypto"/"dumb chip". Nowadays, and for contactless especially, it tends to mean "tag that has an embedded battery"/"tag that is powered by the NFC field". If you interpret it as the latter, it has no impact on the tag functional capabilities, indeed. And I realize my answer isn't quite clear on that. I might update it when I have time.

Comment: @typelogic: and for information, none of the cards I mention above actually embed a battery. Active tags (in the sense "have a battery") are another category of products, which I don't even think about when "RFID cards" are simply mentioned, as in the question title. Which is why I didn't interpret it in that sense.

Answer (score 0):

Note, that NFC just describes the communication method and tells nothing about the intelligence available on other side.

More intelligence is needed (the command you seem to look for is called *EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATE* in ISO 7816-4), but does not help for your range problem, since the weaker the field, the less power is available. The idea of having communication through the door will only work for doors which are so weak, that a high-tech electronic protection won't improve overall security. The maximum distance achievable with standard field strength (heart pacemakers and similar devices limit that one) with nothing more than air between suffices typically for something like 10 centimeters. So for me it seems that your reader has to be on the outside and needs to be mechanically hardened against tampering itself.

(What would help, is a "card" with its own power source, so the field is only required for communication. As far as I know, this is mostly provided by a sort of external sleeve.)

What dim fails to mention is the product group of so-called *native cards*, which are typically only programmable with significant manufacturer support (non-disclosure agreement, probably fee involved), but luckily contain  functionality for most use cases already, in your case the commands *Get Challenge* and *External Authenticate*.

Comment: What he needs is actually INTERNAL AUTHENTICATE. And Mifare / FeliCa / ACOS3 / etc... are native cards. I just called them "general-purpose", but this is exactly what I meant.

Comment: @dim Which authenticate to use depends on, whether you want the card to be involved, which doors it is supposed to open; you are right, that according to the question it would be *Internal*, but this does not have a separate challenge, just the command data field of the Authenticate command. *General purpose* is simply to vague a term to be helpful (Javacards would surely also be a match) and I would not recommend to group a hardwired logic as Mifare with even the simplest processor card: the differences outweigh the similarities by far.

Comment: Instead of exposing the reader itself, I will expose only the antenna outside, while the reader can be inside cable-connected

Comment: In the course of my familiarizations,  my current understanding is that the addition of NFC is meant for intelligent tags. At present, I understand that RFID has one-direction communication from https://www.informsinc.com/rfid-vs-nfc whereas NFC has dual, clearly intended for intelligent communication. The logical conclusion, is that RFID used in tracking cartoons and goods should have tags with fixed states - is my present belief until corrected.